# Dockerfile and docker-compose not updating with new instructions

Tags: docker, containers, dockerfile, docker-compose

When I try to build a container using docker-compose like so

```
nginx:
  build: ./nginx
  ports:
    - "5000:80"
```

the COPY instructions isnt working when my Dockerfile simply 
looks like this

```
FROM nginx

#Expose port 80
EXPOSE 80

COPY html /usr/share/nginx/test

#Start nginx server
RUN service nginx restart
```

What could be the problem?

Answer (score 85):

It seems that when using the ***docker-compose*** command it saves an intermediate container that it doesnt show you and constantly reruns that never updating it correctly. 
   Sadly the documentation regarding something like this is poor.  The way to fix this is to build it first with no cache and then up it like so

```
docker-compose build --no-cache
docker-compose up -d
```

Comment: Yes, it needs to be fixed, see https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/693 and https://github.com/docker/compose/issues/12

Comment: @Kwhitejr has that still not been fixed?!

Comment: The problem still exists for me.  Not sure if it matters, but it worked without using no-cache option.

Comment: Darn, I was working for hours and this was the issue. (My issue was my Dockerfile copied the files when running it by docker build but not when using docker composer) Thanks man you saved my day!

Comment: For a non-composed container: `docker build --no-cache .`

Comment: `docker-compose up --build`

Answer (score 23):

I had the same issue and a one liner that does it for me is :

`docker-compose up --build --remove-orphans --force-recreate`

- `--build` does the biggest part of the job and triggers the build.
- `--remove-orphans` is useful if you have changed the name of one of your services. Otherwise, you might have a warning leftover telling you about the old, now wrongly named service dangling around.
- `--force-recreate` is a little drastic but will force the recreation of the containers.

Reference: https://docs.docker.com/compose/reference/up/

**Warning** I could do this on my project because I was toying around with really small container images. Recreating everything, everytime, could take significant time depending on your situation.

Answer (score 1):

If you need to make docker-compose to copy files every time on `up` command I suggest declaring a `volumes` option to your service in the `compose.yml` file. It will persist your data and also will copy files from that folder into the container.

More info here [volume-configuration-reference](https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#volume-configuration-reference)

```
server:
    image: server
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .envs/.server
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./server_data:/app  # <= here it is
    ports:
      - "9999:9999"
    command: ["command", "to", "run", "the", "server", "--some-options"]
```

Optionally, you can add the following section to the end of the `compose.yml` file. It will keep that folder persisted then. The data in that folder will not be removed after the `docker-compose stop` command or the `docker-compose down` command. To remove the folder you will need to run the `down` command with an additional flag `-v`:

`docker-compose down -v`

For example, including volumes:

```
services:
  server:
    image: server
    container_name: server
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: server.Dockerfile
    env_file:
      - .envs/.server
    working_dir: /app
    volumes:
      - ./server_data:/app  # <= here it is
    ports:
      - "9999:9999"
    command: ["command", "to", "run", "the", "server", "--some-options"]

volumes:  # at the root level, the same as services
  server_data:
```